# SOLVED: How do I create fourier series for $f(x)=x$ in the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I found $a_0$ but I am stuck with $a_n$.

In $a_n$
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} x\cos (nx) dx  \\  a_n= \frac{1}{\pi} \left [x \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \right) + \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2} \right] 
$$

Now what???

**Solution:**

$$
a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}x dx \\ a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{4\pi^2}{2}\right)\\a_0= \pi \\
a_n=0 \\
b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}x\sin(nx)dx \\ bn=\frac{-2\pi n\cos(2\pi n)+sin (2\pi n)}{\pi n^2} \\ bn=-\frac{2}{n}
$$

Hence,

$$
f(x)=\pi-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx) \\ x=\pi-2\left(\sin(x)+\frac{1}{1}\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{1}\sin(3x)+...\right)
$$

Comment: How would you stuck with $a_n$ but found $a_0$?

Comment: What is your formula for $a_n$? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please see the question I have edited it..

Comment: $a_n$ can depend on $n$, but not on $x$. You need to correct something here.

Comment: So how can I find $a_n$ now?

Comment: By evaluating the integral correctly.  Looks like you tried integration by parts.  Work it through.

Comment: @NiraliAcharya, $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{d}x=F(b)-F(a)$, i.e you need to evaluate the function at integration boundaries. Also, as a hint: $f(x)=x$ is odd function, thus $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n=0$.

Comment: @Galc Ok thanks...

Comment: @NiraliAcharya, what about $b_n$? have you managed to find it? can you write down the series?

Comment: @Galc I have written the solution(question edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you do not know integration? This is not an indefinite integral.

You have calculated the antiderivative correctly, you need to take the difference of this between $x=2\pi$ and $x=0$.

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}x\cos(nx)dx = \frac{2\pi n\sin(2\pi n)+\cos(2\pi n)-1}{\pi n^2} = 0$$

Comment: It seems that he integrated fine, but forgot to evaluate. Also, you can use $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:\ \sin(2\pi n)=0,\cos(2\pi n)=1$, thus the integral is $0$.